# parse.com API - how to run a query inside parse classes files?

Tags: objective-c, search, parse-platform, pfquery

I will try to explain myself as best as I can.
My app has a login & sign Up using the Parse API . 
after signing or logging the User see a page with a Button and a Text Field which he can write Numbers in it ,
let's say he write , for example: 1234.

the button job is to save the data from the text field 
Now i'm sure my Button method isn't the best way, but it's work :-)

```
NSString *whoIsTheUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *phoneNumbers = phoneNumberField.text ;



NSString *fullData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ , %@", whoIsTheUser, phoneNumbers];
NSLog(@" %@, %@ ", whoIsTheUser, phoneNumbers);

PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"phoneNumber"];
[addValues setObject: fullData forKey:@"numbers"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```

So now what i'm having  is the data saved to parse site under class of Numbers (forKey:@"numbers") 
and it's look like this :

```
 <PFUser:hqExhaYaIN:(null)> {email = "buffo@yahoo.com";username = buffo;} ,  1234
```

what I'm trying to do is to add another button which going to check if theres another user
who wrote the same numbers and then send an alert or do something . 
I have tried to read about the PFQuery but didn't find any solution. 
is it even possible to run Query in the classes name ? or maybe theres another way to do it ( within the parse site ) ? 
thank you so much for any suggestion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to split up fullData in your parse objects and do something like this

```
PFQuery* numQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"phoneNumber"];
[numQuery whereKey:@"numbers" equalTo:phoneNumbers];
[numQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
     if(!error)
     {
        for(PFObject *numObject in objects)
        {
          //Do what you need to do here
        }
     }
     else
     {
         //handle error
     }
}
```

*EDIT* - this means you would save your PFObjects like this

```
PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"phoneNumber"];
[addValues setObject: phoneNumbers forKey:@"numbers"];
[addValues setObject: whoIsTheUser forKey:@"theUser"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```

Comment: you are right, the split data works perfect , now I can see a column with the user ID . BUT, the if statement is not working. i need to create an If statement with the Current User ID, which means if the current user type 1234, so the search query will skip what the current user typed, so it won't show a match. I still don't understand how your if statement is correct. thank you for any help ! P.S ( again my main concept that if user1 type 1234 and then user2 typed 1234 so user2 will see an UIAlert.

Comment: then in your query, you should limit the results to those that aren't the user. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-constraints/iOS

Comment: well i'll take that as an answer since it's help me

Answer (score 0):

i hope it's going to help someone like it's helps me , if you want to query for info without the user info use those lines

```
PFQuery* numQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"phoneNumber"];
[numQuery whereKey:@"numbers" equalTo:phoneNumbers];
[numQuery whereKey:@"theUser" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[numQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
```

all I had to do is add notEqualTo and CurrentUser :-)